# Receiving Email App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a mail reception problem for my app engine app, I followed the tutorial Google Cloud Platform 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving
but I can't receive any mail. What I receive is a blank page.

appengine-web.xml

```
<inbound-services>
  <service>mail</service>
</inbound-services>
```

web.xml

```
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>MailHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>mail</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

servlet `ReceiveEmailServlet`

```
public class MailHandlerServlet extends HttpServlet { 
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, 
                       HttpServletResponse resp) 
            throws IOException { 
        Properties props = new Properties(); 
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage message =  null;
        try {
            message = new MimeMessage(session, req.getInputStream());
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
<servlet-class>MailHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
```

use a fully-qualifying class name. (E.g., `com.example.project.MailHandlerServlet`)